# How to create a custom ActionColumn in the gridView of yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a gridView and i managed to get it to contain the data i need, but what i need to do next is to create a column which contains two buttons for has_facebook and has_twitter.

```
<?=
 GridView::widget([
     'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
     'filterModel' =>$searchModel,
     'columns'     =>[
         ['class'=>'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
         'name',
         'cm_name',
         'has_facebook',
         'has_twitter',             
         ['class'=>'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
     ],
 ]);
?>
```

### name        | cm_name | platforms

### account1     |  jack   | btn1 btn2

where btn1 and btn2 refer to facebook and twitter.

sorry for the disfigured table.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don't need to create own column Class. You can create simple raw-column and show there anything you want:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'some_title',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($model) {                      
            return '<div>'.$model->id.' and other html-code</div>';
    },
],
```

This function

```
function ($model) {                      
    return '<div>'.$model->id.' and other html-code</div>';
}
```

names callback function. There is core method [evaluateExpression in CComponent](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/base/CComponent.php#L607):

```
public function evaluateExpression($_expression_,$_data_=array())
{
    if(is_string($_expression_))
    {
        extract($_data_);
        return eval('return '.$_expression_.';');
    }
    else
    {
        $_data_[]=$this;
        return call_user_func_array($_expression_, $_data_);
    }
}
```

in our case expression is not string, it's a function, so it runs php method [call_user_func_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) and pass into it your model.

Comment: thank you very much, this is not the first time you've helped me, you've been of great help for me and the rest of the team. @Alex

just one thing, how can the function see the $model? where is it defined, I've tried defining a new one, but didn't work.

Comment: nevermind my comment, i didn't understand at first the $model represented the current instance of the model being processed, thank you again :D @Alex

Comment: return '<div>'. Html::encode($model->id).' and other html-code</div>';

Answer (score 3):

Just a tip:
If you are rendering complex data, this was would be helpful in Yii2..

```
echo yii\grid\GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'columns' => [
    'id',
    [
      'attribute' => 'Details',
      'format' => 'raw',
      'value' => function ($model) {
        return $this->render('//path/to/view.php', ['model' => $model]);
      },
    ]
  ]
]);
```

or you can use

```
echo \yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '//path/to/view.php',
]);
```

and the partial view could be something like

```
<?= Html::img('@web/user/images' . $model->id . '.jpeg', ['alt' => 'Profile Picture', 'class' => 'img img-rounded']); ?>
<?= Html::encode($model->firstName) ?> <?= Html::encode($model->lastName) ?>,
living in <?= Html::encode($model->city) ?> <?= Html::encode($model->country) ?>
```