# How to get the related data in gridview yii advanced

Tags: gridview, yii2

This is my AttributeLang model

```
<?php
namespace backend\models;
use Yii;

class AttributeLang extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord{

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'attribute_lang';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id_attribute', 'id_lang', 'name'], 'required'],
        [['id_attribute', 'id_lang'], 'integer'],
        [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 128]
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id_attribute' => Yii::t('app', 'Id Attribute'),
        'id_lang' => Yii::t('app', 'Id Lang'),
        'name' => Yii::t('app', 'Name'),
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getIdLang()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Lang::className(), ['id_lang' => 'id_lang']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getIdAttribute()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Attribute::className(), ['id_attribute' => 'id_attribute']);
}
```

}

This is my controller

```
public function actionView($id)
{        
    $searchModel = new AttributeSearch();
    $attribute = new Attribute();
    $color = AttributeLang::find()
        ->joinwith('idAttribute')
        ->andWhere('id_attribute_group ='.$id)
        ->all();
    pr($color);die;   

    $dataProvider = $searchModel->newsearch(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);        
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $attribute::findOne($id),
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'color' => $color,           

    ]);
}
```

This is my view file

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,    
'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id_attribute',
        'id_attribute_group',
        'color',  
        'position',                  
    ],  

]); ?>
```

'id_attribute','id_attribute_group','color','position' columns are in attribute table.

How to show an extra cloumn "name" from attribute_lang table inside gridview.

If I print $color the result is as below in image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYoYG.png)

Comment: Show the controller for this view please..

Comment: I have added controller.

Comment: Please add also the AttributeLang model (complete) please

Comment: But Attribute and AttributeLang are two different models?.. and the controller you showed with which model is related)

Comment: Model is added.
So, how can i show the related column name?

Comment: The controller actionView is for AttributeLang and the $id is an id of AttributeLang ? please confirm or explain

Comment: No, the $id is the pk for attribute_group table.

Comment: I don't understand, which relation exist between AttributeLand, Attribute and eventually AttributeGruop ... a piece missing

Comment: Describe your schema,  from where do you start and your goal..

Comment: Added an image. I need this column "name":L in gridview.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342035/how-to-create-a-custom-actioncolumn-in-the-gridview-of-yii2

Comment: If you haven't already solved, please show also the Attribute Model

Answer (score 0):

if you used gii to generate model, and if in attribute view you want to show name of related attribute_lang, it should be something like this: 'attributeLang.name'